# conditionally set data-toggle attributes in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button (**type='submit'**) inside a form that has an attribute (**data-toggle='modal'**). onclick the button triggers the modal immediately. But I want to validate the form first and then trigger the modal if all input field is validated.

so what I've tried. Below is the simplified version of the form.

*

```
           <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
             <button
              data-toggle={this.state.validatedForm ? "modal" : ""}
              data-target="#request_search_submit_popup_door_to_door"
              type="submit"
              className="search-button"
            >
              <span>
                <i className="icofont-search-1"></i>
              </span>
            </button>
            </form>
```

- 

here I am initializing the state as below

```
this.state={
    validatedForm:false
}
```

if all the input field is validated then only the **handleSubmit** method will be called. And in there I  am changing the state to

```
handleSubmit =(event)=>{
   event.preventDefault()
   this.setState({validatedForm:true})
}
```

but for the first submit the button doesn't trigger the modal. I am assuming the data-toggle attribute is only checking the value of **validatedForm** once.Doesn't check the value of **validatedForm** again after the handleSubmit is called. How can I achieve the functionality without using jquery.
and point to be noted if I click on the button twice it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
  const conditionals = {};
  if (this.state.validatedForm === "modal") {
    conditionals['data-toggle'] = 'modal';
  }

  return <button data-target={"xxx"} { ...conditionals} />
}
```

Comment: This also doesn't work. I think I know what is wrong with this code. but can't find the solution to this. In the initial rendering, the button has no data-toggle attribute. then users click on the button. if the form is validated then handleSubmit method is called. then the state is changed (validatedFrom=true). the component renders again. now the data-toggle attribute is there. but the button is never clicked again.

Comment: I have solved the attribute issue, there might be other things going on with your code or logic :)

Comment: The problem you solved is already solved twice brother. You are setting the data-toggle attribute equal to modal based on a condition. But that doesn't trigger the modal. How is the problem solved? And there is obviously no css or bootstrap issue. Because if I plainly set data-toggle='modal'. clicking on the button triggers the modal. but if I put it in a condition the modal isn't showing up.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the cleanest solution. but I did a simple trick to get thing working for me. In handleSubmit method just click on the button again.

```
           <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
             <button
              id="form-submit-button"
              {...(this.state.validatedForm ?{'data-toggle': "modal"} : {})}
              data-target="#request_search_submit_popup_door_to_door"
              type="submit"
              className="search-button"
            >
              <span>
                <i className="icofont-search-1"></i>
              </span>
            </button>
           </form>


     handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ validatedForm: true }, () => {
          document.getElementById("form-submit-button").click();
        });
     }
```

In initial render **this.state.validateFrom=false**. so no data-toggle attribute is there on submit button. users clicks on the submit button if the form is not validated handleSubmit is not called. but if the form is validated handleSubmit method gets called. state is changed to **validatedForm = true**. Now data-toggle attribute is there on the submit button. just clicking on the button again triggered the modal for me.